# Large amounts of text - mysql or flatfile?

Tags: php, mysql, text

I am writing a web application in PHP that will store large numbers of blocks of arbitrary length text. Is MySQL well suited for this task with a longtext field or similar, or should I store each block of text in its own file and use a MySQL table for indexes and filenames? Think online bulletin board type stuff, like how you would store each users posts.

Comment: bulletin boards post seldom exceed few kilobytes. I see nothing in common with your case.

Comment: Well I just thought it would help people understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, MySQL is the way to go. A flat file would take much longer to search etc.

Mysql all the way. Much more efficient.

Comment: Ok. I was hesitant to use it for stuff as huge as it will be used for, but if its better for even stuff like 100,000 character long texts then mysql it is.

Comment: I don't know about MySQL, but I store blobs up to 10MB in my database with no problem.